# LinkedIn API: Find Organization by Vanity Name endpoint returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: linkedin-api

I keep receiving 500 Internal Server Error for the endpoint "Find Organization by Vanity Name" . I tried with the 202307 and 202311 versions, but I get the same result. In the documentation, I didn't saw any changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http#find-organization-by-vanity-name

My request:

```
curl --location 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=LinkedIn' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202311' \
--header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ...
```

What I get:

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error","status":500}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour, filed a support request to LinkedIn, did you figure out how to solve it on your end?

Comment: @Gregory, Carina I've got the same problem, did Linkedin answered the support request?

Comment: Seems like it works with the old domain path `api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations`

Comment: Hello and sorry for the late reply. I talked to them and they told me that this issue is going to be handled in 202312 version, but till then the version 202306 still works. I hope this help